# How to make bootstrap.dat work with bitcoin qt

Tags: bitcoin-core, bootstrap.dat

- I have downloaded the bootstrap.dat torrent to make bitcoin qt synchronize faster.
- I have searched the bitcoin directory by writing in the Run Application "explorer %APPDATA%\Bitcoin"
- I have dropped the bootstrap.dat file in there. (other files/maps in there are, blocks, chainstate, .lock, db, debug, peers.dat, wallet.dat/
- I have opened the bitcoin qt program through Start.

And the bitcoin qt is not importing the bootstrap.dat. It just start synchronizing from 5 years.

Can someone tell me how to solve this

Answer (score 1):

The importing process is not instant, every block from the bootstrap.dat has to be verified first.

You could be looking at this process of verification.

Comment: But how do I know that Iam in a process of verifaction. It just looks like its synchronizing like it does without the bootstrap.dat. Is this normal?

Comment: The most important distinction would be that it goes faster :-)

Comment: The latest version shows network activity graph. That should be 0 or low when merely verifying.